# How to change Visual Studio C++ initialization sequence for const string arrays in statically linked libraries

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I'm making some changes to a legacy application (CWinApp) in Visual Studio 2013, that uses a legacy statically linked library. I'm having problems in getting const string arrays initialized in the application.

To make things easier, I've created a basic example that demonstrates the issue. The example consists of a CWinApp application (class CTestApp), that references static library MyLib.lib. CTestApp owns an object of type MyClass that's defined in MyLib. Here are some code extracts:

### Main Application (CTestApp)

**TestApp.h:**

```
class CTestApp : public CWinApp
{
   // --- Standard Wizard generated CWinApp stuff here ---
private:
   MyClass mine;
};
```

**TestApp.cpp:**

```
// --- Standard Wizard generated CWinApp stuff here ---

CTestApp::CTestApp()
   : mine(55)
{
}
```

### Static Library (MyLib.lib)

**MyClass.h:**

```
#pragma once

#include <string>

const std::string ids[] =
{
   "ABC",
   "DEF",
   "GHI"
};
const int num_ids = 3;

class MyClass
{
public:
   MyClass(int id);
private:
   int id;
   std::string name;
};
```

**MyClass.cpp:**

```
#include "MyClass.h"

MyClass::MyClass(int id)
: id(id)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < num_ids; ++i)
   {
      name += ids[i];
   }
}
```

The problem is that when stepping through `CTestApp::CTestApp` into `MyClass::MyClass`, I find that the strings in array `ids` are empty. What's also strange is that the integer constant `num_ids` is initialized to `3` as expected. This seems to only happen for const string arrays declared in static libraries. If I declare a similar array within `CTestApp` itself, it is initialized by the time I step into `CTestApp::CTestApp`.

I also find that if I run the application and break in `CTestApp::InitInstance` then `ids` has been initialized correctly.

Is there a way to force Visual Studio to initialize const string arrays such as this before entering the member initialization section of `CTestApp::CTestApp`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really. You can probably solve your specific case, though.

`ids` is a global variable with dynamic initialization.

So is your global `CTestApp` object.

`ids` is defined everywhere that includes the header. The `app` object is probably defined in some main file.

The order of dynamic initialization of globals in different modules (.cpp files) is unspecified by C++. It can differ from compilation to compilation, from compiler to compiler. You don't want to depend on it.

If you need to guarantee an order, the only way is to put the initialization into the same module. A single module is initialized in order of declaration.

So the solution for your specific case is: declare `ids` as `extern` in the header, and actually define it alongside your global `app`, just before. However, that doesn't scale as you get more classes.

Alternatively, make `ids` a true constant by changing it to an array of `const char*`. That would make it get initialized statically, which happens before dynamic initialization.

Finally, you could change `mine` to a (smart) pointer and only initialize it in `InitInstance`.

Comment: That's a nice wrapup of solutions to a (somewhat) common problem. I usually go for the `const char *`.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian, you've given some good alternatives. Although I used a string array in the question for simplicity, the legacy code I'm working on actually contains a whole bunch of const arrays of structs with constant strings declared within each array initialization. I found by changing `string` to `const char *` in the struct definition, I was able to fix the problem with very minor code changes. At this stage the less I change the code the better.